# Can't get webpack-dev-server running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am having some trouble getting my react app to run. I have tried multiple things, downgrading webpack version, doing `npm i -g webpack-dev-server` and even `npm i -g webpack-cli` and nothing is working. Below is the error message I am getting. Would appreciate any suggestions or help you may be able to provide.

```
 $ node ../../bin/env.js webpack-dev-server
    [dev:main] 'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    [dev:main] operable program or batch file.
    [dev:main] events.js:291
    [dev:main]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    [dev:main]       ^
    [dev:main]
    [dev:main] Error: spawn webpack-dev-server ENOENT
    [dev:main]     at notFoundError (C:\Users\Nil Amrutlal\Projects\dtnl-abn-aditium\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    [dev:main]     at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Nil Amrutlal\Projects\dtnl-abn-aditium\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    [dev:main]     at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Nil Amrutlal\Projects\dtnl-abn-aditium\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    [dev:main]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
    [dev:main] Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    [dev:main]     at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Nil Amrutlal\Projects\dtnl-abn-aditium\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    [dev:main]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12) {
    [dev:main]   code: 'ENOENT',
    [dev:main]   errno: 'ENOENT',
    [dev:main]   syscall: 'spawn webpack-dev-server',
    [dev:main]   path: 'webpack-dev-server',
    [dev:main]   spawnargs: []
    [dev:main] }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server#with-the-cli

It should be:

```
webpack serve
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to downgrade your webpack version, but in order for the `webpack-dev-server` to run, you have to do minimum configuration as well in your `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` files alongside installation.

`webpack.config.js` file

```
//...
module.exports = {
//...
    devServer: {
      static: './dist',
    },
//...
};
```

`package.json` file

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
 "start": "webpack serve --open",
  "build": "webpack"
},
```

Now do `yarn start` (or `npm start`) and you should get your webpack server running.